# Connect to docker container that runs golang server using netcat

Tags: docker, go, netcat

I'm new to docker. Trying to create an image from a simple server written in golang. Server listens on port 8000 and writes current time to the client once per second.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        fmt.Println("Received connection")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        _, err := io.WriteString(conn, time.Now().Format("15:04:05\n"))
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM golang

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/
RUN mkdir -p sandbox/clock1
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/sandbox/clock1

COPY . .

RUN go get -d -v ./...

RUN go install -v ./...

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/clock1
```

I start docker container with command

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -it --name clock1 clock1
```

And then I'm trying to connect to server using docker IP address

```
nc 192.168.1.3 8000
```

netcat fails to connect and exists immediately. Could you please point me to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In you server, listen :8000 instead of localhost:8000

Comment: or `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`